# How to detect product name from the bill text?

Tags: nlp

I have to detect price and product name from given text.

Where should I look to if I am new to this topic ?

I don't know all product names. It can be anything.

**Example 1**

`Hello Denys, thank you for purchasing beer. Enjoy!`

**Example 2**

`Hello Denys, here is your peanuts.`

Products are - **beer, peanuts**.

P.S. I'm familiar with Ruby and found this library - https://github.com/jekyll/classifier-reborn. Is it applicable to this task ?

Comment: Are you dealing with unstructured (informal) data?

Comment: @ShuaiYuan for example - it can be email or any PDF receipt

Comment: Regular expressions

Comment: @xtian added examples. We don't have all examples of texts. There can be any kind of text.

Comment: If you have a dictionary of products the problem becomes trivial

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev I don't have product names.

Comment: Then get them. There are a couple of datasets with names available online or you can create these datasets yourself by scraping the web

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev thanks. After some research and thoughts it seems to be the only way.